# Text output in wrong order

Tags: python, json

I have the following Python code.

```
import json
temp_string = ""

with open("data_elements.json") as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data:
        this_ldraw = p["ldraw"]
        this_lgeo = p["lgeo"]
        this_ldraw = this_ldraw.strip(".dat")
        this_lgeo = this_lgeo.strip("lg_")
        this_lgeo = this_lgeo.strip(".inc")
        print(this_ldraw + "\t" + this_lgeo)
```

I have some JSON:

```
[
{"ldraw":"003238a.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238a.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238b.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238b.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238c.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238c.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238d.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238d.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238e.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238e.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238f.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238f.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238g.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238g.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238h.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238h.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238i.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238i.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"},
{"ldraw":"003238j.dat","lgeo":"lg_003238j.inc","slope":"0","anton":"0","lutz":"0","owen":"0","darats":"0"}
]
```

The Python script is supposed to process the "ldraw" column and the "lgeo" column such that the result of the processing is two identical columns in the output. However, the output is not in the correct order.

The output looks like this:

```
003238  003238a
003238b 003238b
003238c 003238
003238  003238d
003238e 003238e
003238f 003238f
003238g 003238g
003238h 003238h
003238i 003238
003238j 003238j
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.2.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in python 2.7

Comment: I think you should read what the strip function actually does and try slicing the strings instead

Comment: if they're always the same, can you read one and then check if it exists in the other?